# Open Google maps app only on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I have website that has Google Map.

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

That is the div in my website where is the map.

```
function initMap() {
    const mapContainer = document.getElementById('map');
    const location = {lat: 44.116395, lng: 27.261184};

    const map = new google.maps.Map(mapContainer, {
        zoom: 17,
        center: location
    });

    const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map
    });
}
```

That's map code in javascript file.
When website is opened by computer, I want nothing to happen. When website is opened by mobile or tablet, I want when someone click on the map, Google Map App to be opened. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use media queries in jquery to find out whether the user is using mobile or not.

In your case I'd recommend using matchmedia queries: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_matchmedia.asp

```
if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 700px)").matches) {
    /* The viewport is less than, or equal to, 700 pixels wide */
} else {
    /* The viewport is greater than 700 pixels wide */
}
```

If it's not mobile change the "initMap()" code to something that does not return a map and voilà - map gone.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#universal-cross-platform-syntax